# Status bar colors and resources

Tags: android

I'm creating my own remote view for the status bar(notification center). I want the remote view to have the same background color as the other notifications and I want it to be consistent across devices, e.g. Samsung and stock Android.

The only layout information I managed to find was under \android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\layout\status_bar_latest_event_content.xml
In addition I found [icon guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) however I couldn't find anything related to background color.

I played with Photoshop and found the default color for Stock Android (#111111), however I don't want to hard code it.

When not using any background color the default that I get is grayish (see attachment)

[image]

Any suggestions ?